# Scroll to a div (slow scroll animate) JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am writing to you because I have a problem with animation scroll to the specific section. Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it?
Currently jumps me to a specific section, but not going down slowly.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <div id="sidebar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#section1">O Firmie <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Flota</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Oferta</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#section4">Kontakt:</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="slider" id="section1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae elit non ipsum volutpat commodo nec eget odio. Vestibulum ut enim leo. Mauris 
    <br /><br /><br />
    </div>

    <div class="o_firmie" id="section2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae elit non ipsum volutpat commodo nec eget odio. Vestibulum ut enim leo.  ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
    </div>

    <div class="mapa" id="section3">
 finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
        </div>

    <div class="flota" id="section4">
  facilisis ac faucibus purus. Praesent eleifend nisi nulla, vitae imperdiet nulla rhoncus quis. Nunc vel lacus sapien. Curabitur euismod augue et sem malesuada finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
    </div>

    <div class="footer" id="section5">
     malesuada finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
    </div>
```

JS Code:

```
 function goToByScroll(id){
          // Scroll
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
            'slow');
    }

    $("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
          // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
        e.preventDefault(); 
          // Call the scroll function
        goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));           
    });
```

Here is my live demo:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/3022/
```

How can i fix it quick?

Thanks for Your reply guys

Comment: provided jsfiddle not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
function goToByScroll(id){
      // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
        },
        'slow');
}

$("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
      // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
    e.preventDefault(); 
      // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <div id="sidebar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">O Firmie <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Flota</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Oferta</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#section4">Kontakt:</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="slider" id="section1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae elit non ipsum volutpat commodo nec eget odio. Vestibulum ut enim leo. Mauris varius pellentesque aliquam. Nullam commodo urna orci, quis elementum magna venenatis eget. Mauris placerat neque enim, imperdiet scelerisque est consequat vitae. Sed nulla tellus, pulvinar non viverra eget, blandit id diam. Morbi sagittis, est ut elementum congue, ante risus vulputate eros, a fringilla lorem dolor et tellus. Curabitur elit ex, aliquet eu justo id, vulputate blandit enim. Curabitur egestas ac dolor nec ultrices. Aliquam ut ipsum vel nisl eleifend facilisis ac faucibus purus. Praesent eleifend nisi nulla, vitae imperdiet nulla rhoncus quis. Nunc vel lacus sapien. Curabitur euismod augue et sem malesuada finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.
<br /><br /><br />
</div>

<!-- MODUŁ O FIRMIE -->

<div class="o_firmie" id="section2">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae elit non ipsum volutpat commodo nec eget odio. Vestibulum ut enim leo. Mauris varius pellentesque aliquam. Nullam commodo urna orci, quis elementum magna venenatis eget. Mauris placerat neque enim, imperdiet scelerisque est consequat vitae. Sed nulla tellus, pulvinar non viverra eget, blandit id diam. Morbi sagittis, est ut elementum congue, ante risus vulputate eros, a fringilla lorem dolor et tellus. Curabitur elit ex, aliquet eu justo id, vulputate blandit enim. Curabitur egestas ac dolor nec ultrices. Aliquam ut ipsum vel nisl eleifend facilisis ac faucibus purus. Praesent eleifend nisi nulla, vitae imperdiet nulla rhoncus quis. Nunc vel lacus sapien. Curabitur euismod augue et sem malesuada finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
</div>


<div class="mapa" id="section3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae elit non ipsum volutpat commodo nec eget odio. Vestibulum ut enim leo. Mauris varius pellentesque aliquam. Nullam commodo urna orci, quis elementum magna venenatis eget. Mauris placerat neque enim, imperdiet scelerisque est consequat vitae. Sed nulla tellus, pulvinar non viverra eget, blandit id diam. Morbi sagittis, est ut elementum congue, ante risus vulputate eros, a fringilla lorem dolor et tellus. Curabitur elit ex, aliquet eu justo id, vulputate blandit enim. Curabitur egestas ac dolor nec ultrices. Aliquam ut ipsum vel nisl eleifend facilisis ac faucibus purus. Praesent eleifend nisi nulla, vitae imperdiet nulla rhoncus quis. Nunc vel lacus sapien. Curabitur euismod augue et sem malesuada finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
 </div>

<div class="flota" id="section4">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae elit non ipsum volutpat commodo nec eget odio. Vestibulum ut enim leo. Mauris varius pellentesque aliquam. Nullam commodo urna orci, quis elementum magna venenatis eget. Mauris placerat neque enim, imperdiet scelerisque est consequat vitae. Sed nulla tellus, pulvinar non viverra eget, blandit id diam. Morbi sagittis, est ut elementum congue, ante risus vulputate eros, a fringilla lorem dolor et tellus. Curabitur elit ex, aliquet eu justo id, vulputate blandit enim. Curabitur egestas ac dolor nec ultrices. Aliquam ut ipsum vel nisl eleifend facilisis ac faucibus purus. Praesent eleifend nisi nulla, vitae imperdiet nulla rhoncus quis. Nunc vel lacus sapien. Curabitur euismod augue et sem malesuada finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
</div>

<div class="footer" id="section5">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae elit non ipsum volutpat commodo nec eget odio. Vestibulum ut enim leo. Mauris varius pellentesque aliquam. Nullam commodo urna orci, quis elementum magna venenatis eget. Mauris placerat neque enim, imperdiet scelerisque est consequat vitae. Sed nulla tellus, pulvinar non viverra eget, blandit id diam. Morbi sagittis, est ut elementum congue, ante risus vulputate eros, a fringilla lorem dolor et tellus. Curabitur elit ex, aliquet eu justo id, vulputate blandit enim. Curabitur egestas ac dolor nec ultrices. Aliquam ut ipsum vel nisl eleifend facilisis ac faucibus purus. Praesent eleifend nisi nulla, vitae imperdiet nulla rhoncus quis. Nunc vel lacus sapien. Curabitur euismod augue et sem malesuada finibus. Integer malesuada, ante vitae auctor accumsan, quam eros maximus risus, vitae sollicitudin justo magna porttitor augue. Quisque facilisis ac enim sit amet viverra.<br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: @Giacomo
That's because I forget include jQuery! Please reload page and try again

Comment: Still doesn't work. Only jump to section, zero animation :(

Comment: Which browser are you use?

Comment: I use Google Chrome, but this same is in Firefox

Comment: Your $ code is evaluated before $ is ready. Wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function(){  ...  });`  (or in jsfiddle set the javascript loadType to onDomready.

Comment: This is magic :)
I also use Chrome and my snippet work fine
Try this link - http://jsfiddle.net/igogo5yo/VPzxG/3025/

Comment: True, it is work in my chrome too. But in my local files doesn't work :(

Comment: Lol, i did $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); in my local custom.js, and it is work. Whaaaaat? x)

Comment: Like I said ;) BTW, test your code in your browser tool using `console.log`. And use `$.ready` or better yet: `$(function(){...}` ... read https://api.jquery.com/ready/